# Passing Multiple Variable into a view

Tags: php, laravel

How do I pass a multiple variable into a view and how do I get it?

supposing i have a two variable

```
$dateFrom = 2016-02-22
$dateTo = 2016-02-25

am i doing right with my route?
 return View('admin.inventory-bloodCollectionView1')->with($dateFrom)->with($dateTo);   
and how do i get it from the view?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alias the name of the variable as the first, argument, like so:

```
return View('admin.inventory-bloodCollectionView1')
   ->with('dateFrom', $dateFrom)
   ->with('dateTo', $dateTo);
```

Now they are available in the view as `$dateTo` and `$dateFrom`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple variables or items in to the view by supplying an array to the view method. For example :

```
return view('view_name', ['value_name' => value , 'value_name2' => value2 ]);
```

U can use the items in the view now using : 
$value_name and $value_name2 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Another convenient way to pass variables is using compact.

```
return View('admin.inventory-bloodCollectionView1', compact('dateFrom', 'dateTo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass in the form of array just like this.

```
return view('admin.inventory-bloodCollectionView1')
   ->with(array('fromDate' => $dateFrom, 'toDate'=> $dateTo));
```

These variables will be available in view as $fromDate and $toDate.